# get result from a call of registered event method and send it to class that called it?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am using a button to call a method available in my  `Sub`  class from a `Main` class

How can I retrieve result of type `myObject` gotten when calling `executeMethodDelegate()` inside `Sub` class
if that method must register event first and wait until is complete?

While debugging I noticed that when `sub_myClick` is executed it does not wait the 
event called inside `executeMethodDelegate()` So everything is computed the right way but can not 
use result in Main class...

Main

```
void sub_myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sub.executeMethodDelegate();   //I have object Sub available with all its functions
}
```

Inside `Sub` I execute an event that must interact with user to allow him pick an object of type `myObject` themethod is `getPicked`

inside `executeMethodDelegate` I register event LeftButtonReleaseEvt like:

```
    public void executeMethodDelegate()
    {
        myInteractorStyle pick = myInteractorStyle.New();
        pick.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += (s, args) => getPicked(OnLeftButtonUp(s, args));               
        //here it will register and do the event to select an object    
        //how can I return      myObject result to main class
        //when      getPicked finishs it would return myObject but do not know how to return it to  
    }
    private myObject OnLeftButtonUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //compute some stuff
        //...
        //...  
        //create object of type myObject named result           
        return result;
    }  
    public myObject getPicked(myObject result)
    {
        //result is manipulated given certain conditions that is why the anonymous function
        //then would like to return result of type myObject to executeMethodDelegate()
        return result;
    }
```

So my problem is How to recover event result and send it back to Main class
How can I retrieve and send result to Main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Sub` class can expose a `GotPicked` event which contains `myObject` in its `EventArgs` and then yoi van register to it in your `Main` class

Main:

```
public Main()
{
    Sub.GotPicked += OnGotPicked
}

void sub_myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Sub.executeMethodDelegate();   //I have object Sub available with all its functions
}

public void OnGotPicked(object sender, SubEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with myObject
    var myObject = e.MyObject;
}

public class SubEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SubEventArgs(MyObject obj)
    {
          MyObject = obj;
    }

    public readonly MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

Sub:

```
public event EventHandler<SubEventArgs> GotPicked;

public void getPicked(myObject result)
{
     // Do stuff woth result
            GotPicked(this, new SubEventArgs(result);
```

Comment: I was thinking on wating inside method until event is captured and then return result, is this an option too?

Comment: MMM I tried `AutoResetEvent`  inside sub class method and app locks. then I tried it on main class and it locks... What can I do if my sub class already inherits from user control to use your sample code?

Comment: I dont understand why you want to wait.

Comment: well It wan an idea but I noticed it does not work, Could you please explain a little more yor answer, I do not get it at all

Comment: Your problem is returning your object after your event completes. So what i did is create an event which will be ibvoked after `MyObject` has been modified. The `Main` class will register to that event an that is how you can get the modified `MyObject`.